# Locale and dynamic multi language support in EXJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

According to docs, the app.json only allows to define one locale.

> locale: "fr"

What happens if I have a multiple language application and I want users to select dynamically their language?

How can I include more than one locale ?

And then, how can I dynamically load the locale with just changing an Ext variable ? Something like:

> Ext.setLocale("es");

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs is not able to do this natively.

In my application I have solved this by defining a language class that works similar to gettext.

This allows me to have the code base in the default language with every string wrapped in the function Lang._('My text'). The translation is then done independently of ExtJs (In my case the translation interface is written in ExtJs, but the translation itself is independent).

I still cannot change the language dynamically. For this, I need to rerender the application in the browser. In my case, the translations are compiled into `app.js`, and therefore there is no need to reload `app.js` from the server.

I have only two languages, so this approach is OK. If you need to support many language, the best way is to load the translation string before rendering the application. To switch the language, you need then to load the translation and rerender the UI.

There is a good article about this on [Saki's ExtJs site](http://extjs.eu/localization-of-ext-applications/).

Comment: I have already implemented `gettext` override which you have suggested, but problem is, for by default text of extjs are not getting replaced by locale. like calendar,warning message and confirmation message etc because we can only configure one locale in app.json file. it will be helpful if you provide solution for that.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. Until now I did not takle this problem. I let text constants of the framework in English.